# How to get real urls in html css (Without #)

Tags: html, hyperlink

I've been using hashtag(#) with navigation menu button links, to avoid error. When you are using # you can just click on the link button and it does nothin'. Now I want to get real urls of my site. I can copy like facebook site's url, github site's url and make it as a link button on my site, but I want to have my own website's link. for EX: when you click "About me" button and new page appears on the screen and it's all about me (not blankpage) :D do I need to create another html document?. please help! SOS! THANK YOU!

Comment: just create a new html file and link to it like you do with the #

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.